# Anime or Animation?

Tags: loanwords

I was reading an article about loan words and came across anime(Anime アニメ ---- animation). I later talked with one of my Japanese-speaking friends, and he did not recognize the word anime, he recognized animation. Is their a difference in the two word and how would i refer to the media?

Here is the website for the [article](https://www.thoughtco.com/most-common-loan-words-in-japanese-2027852)
thank you for your help :) -

Comment: I'm guessing this is a pronunciation issue. アニメ is a common word in Japanese, but it has also become a common word in English with markedly different pronunciation of all three syllables.

Comment: I agree, there is no way a Japanese person (excluding elderly) wouldn't know the word アニメ. In Japanese it is much more important to pronounce words properly than in e.g. English, or many will simply not recognize what you are saying. I suppose this could be both because of the fact that Japanese has few phonemes and many homonyms, but also because they are not as used to foreign accents as e.g. English speakers are.

Answer (score 1):

Although they might be interchangeable recently, **Animation** is regarded as full-animation like Disney, whereas **Anime** is regarded as the limited animation was developed in Japan in reaction to the realism of Disney’s animation to keep production time and costs down.

Summary from the reference: No.2 and No.3.

According to an article from a magazine "ケトル", Osamu Tezuka, one of the most famous cartoonists in Japan, was dreaming of making an animation film like Disney. Although it was too expensive for Tezuka as an individual to make such a full animation film since it required more than 100 staff and several million dollars as a budget.So when he was asked to make an animation for weekly 30 minutes television programme, he was trying to reduce the number of images in one movie and restrict essential motion such as the mouth, hands and so on. Ιt had 10 times fewer images than 30 minutes full-animation like Disney. Because it was a surprisingly small number of images in one animation at that time, he called it　**「これはアニメーションでなく、アニメだ」**  Also, he was not content with a short animation like Tom and Jerry which was popular then and simply playing gag and action. For 30-minutes, it was possible for him to make an animation based on a dramatic story and it was luckily acclaimed by the audience and became what is now called **アニメ**.

References:

1. Full animation: Cornell University Literature and Media in Japan Glossary. (You can see a bit of a full animation making)
   https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/asian3318/Full+Animation
2. *「アニメーション」が「アニメ」に　「鉄腕アトム」がもたらした功績: 太田出版ケトルニュース*

   http://www.ohtabooks.com/qjkettle/news/2017/03/03094617.html
3. *手塚治虫が説明した「アニメ」と「アニメーション」の違いとは: 太田出版ケトルニュース* http://www.ohtabooks.com/qjkettle/news/2017/03/09111933.html